# Edimax EW-7811Un very slow if connected at boot

Tags: wifi, internet, raspbian-stretch

When I turn on my Raspberry with the Edimax EW-7811Un plugged in, I get very slow internet (about 200kb/s). But if I boot up my Pi without the dongle and then plug it in after the startup, I get the maximum available download rate in my network (about 10mb/s).

I used another Wifi-Dongle from a friend (Samsung WIS09ABGN2), and everything worked perfectly. Also if I start my Pi with the Samsung dongle and then replace it with the Edimax one, everything works fine.

Do you have any ideas why I don't get the full speed with the Edimax dongle plugged in at startup?

I am using a RaspberryPi3 with the latest Stretch Desktop version. Using the internal Wifi is not an option, cause I need both to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 8192cu module doesn't work properly with that adapter, and the old rtl8912cu module is blacklisted by default in stretch. You need to unblacklist the old rtl8912cu module and blacklist the new one:

```
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf
echo "blacklist 8192cu" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-8192cu.conf
reboot
```

Comment: Blacklisting the module means it will not load automatically; the O.P. will have to `sudo modprobe 8192cu` after plugging in the dongle.

Comment: @user86810, goldilocks  is trying to help you, please learn to take the criticism, it will benefit you in the long term.

Comment: @Darth Vader the 8192cu module is what causes the problem, and its already loaded by default anyway, so his advice is wrong